# What limitations does the GIL impose on using GStreamer through PyGObject?

Tags: python, gstreamer, cpython, pygobject, gil

I have a pretty straightforward `GStreamer` pipeline built using `PyGObject`. It gathers images emitted from a camera:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst


Gst.init([])


class RawCamera:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
            "camsrc ! "  # proprietary camera source
            "capsfilter caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR ! "  # filter for frames of this format
            "videoconvert ! "  # convert to suitable video format
            "appsink name=sink"  # feed frames to application
        )
        sink = self.pipeline.get_by_name("sink")
        sink.set_property("emit-signals", True)
        sink.connect("new-sample", self.on_new_frame)
        self.images = []

    def start(self):
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    def pause(self):
        self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)

    def on_new_frame(self, appsink):
        sample = appsink.emit("pull-sample")

        # Get the actual data
        buffer = sample.get_buffer()
        # Get read access to the buffer data
        success, map_info = buffer.map(Gst.MapFlags.READ)
        self.images.append(map_info.data)
        return Gst.FlowReturn.OK
```

However I'm struggling to understand how `GStreamer` pipeline operates here. I understand that there is/are some "`GStreamer` thread(s)" in the background handling frames emitted from the camera.

But, there are a few things about these threads which I don't understand:

- Does the `GStreamer` pipeline run in the same process as my Python application?
- If so, are the `GStreamer` threads subject to the GIL?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, PyGObject is a native binding so GStreamer runs in the same process.
2. Some do. GStreamer creates its own threads - for instance, each pipeline has a streaming thread which handles most of the actual processing. There is also a thread for the message bus (how events are passed back to Python) which is subject to the GIL when running your callback.